# C# ASP.NET adding a list of properties to individual users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am trying to learn how to create Web ASP.NET applications and I'm stuck on trying to get to this result.

```
{
  "memberNumber":"1234567890",
  "forename":"Fred",
  "surname":"Smith",
  "products":[
    {
      "name":"Health Ins",
      "cost":100
    },
    {
      "name":"Travel Ins",
      "cost":150
    }
  ]
}
```

I cannot figure out how to add different product name/cost for each individual member. I can display the memberNumber/forename/surname but get an error when I add the products.add line to the members.add line.

Here is my member model:

```
public class Member
    {
        public int memberNumber { get; set; } = 0;
        public string forename { get; set; } = "";
        public string surname { get; set; } = "";
        public List<Products> products { get; set; }
    }

    public class Products
    {
        public string name { get; set; } = "";
        public int cost { get; set; } = 0;
    }
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class MembersController : ApiController
    {
        List<Member> members = new List<Member>();
        List<Products> products = new List<Products>();

        public MembersController()
        {
            members.Add(new Member { memberNumber = 1234567890, forename = "Fred", surname = "Smith"});
            members.Add(new Member { memberNumber = 1, forename = "Big", surname = "Ben"});
            members.Add(new Member { memberNumber = 2, forename = "Jack", surname = "Ryan" });

            products.Add(new Products { name = "Health Ins", cost = 100 });
            products.Add(new Products { name = "Travel Ins", cost = 150 });
        }
        // GET: api/Members
        public List<Member> Get()
        {
            return members;
        }

        // GET: api/Members/5
        public Member Get(int id)
        {
            return members.Where(x => x.memberNumber == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Did not include the Post/Put/Delete RESTful services.

Comment: Each Member has a `List<Product>`. So you need to add your product to that list not to a local list of product. For example, to add products to your first member you have to write _members[0].products = products;_ of course a different member could have a different list of products.

Comment: Renaming what you've named `Products` to `Product` might help in not getting confused. Each instance represents a single product, thus a `List<Product>` is indeed the `Member.products`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much there, but you will need to assign a product list for each member like this:

```
  List<Products> p= new List<Products>();
  p.Add(new Products { name = "Health Ins", cost = 100 });
  p.Add(new Products { name = "Travel Ins", cost = 150 });    
  members.Add(new Member { memberNumber = 1234567890, forename = "Fred", surname = "Smith", Products =p});

 // Second member
  p= new List<Products>();
  p.Add(new Products { name = "Big Bens products", cost = 222});        
  members.Add(new Member { memberNumber = 1, forename = "Big", surname = "Ben", Products =p});
```

Thus you can add as many members containing as many products you wish. Please note that we're not talking about ArrayLists but about Lists. ArrayLists have been deprecated a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
products.Add(new Products { name = "Health Ins", cost = 100 });
products.Add(new Products { name = "Travel Ins", cost = 150 });
```

will add those data in

```
List<Products> products = new List<Products>();
```

instead of your expectations in `Member` class.

I think you might want to add `products` collection in a member instead of another `List`

You can use [Auto-Property Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#auto-property-initializers) to init `products` List collection in `Member` class.

```
public class Member
{
    public int memberNumber { get; set; } = 0;
    public string forename { get; set; } = "";
    public string surname { get; set; } = "";
    public List<Products> products { get; set; } = new List<Products>();
}
```

the `MembersController` constructed data will be like this.

```
public class MembersController : ApiController
{
    List<Member> members = new List<Member>();
    public MembersController()
    {
        var member1 = new Member { memberNumber = 1234567890, forename = "Fred", surname = "Smith"};
        var member2 = new Member { memberNumber = 1, forename = "Big", surname = "Ben"};
        var member3 = new Member { memberNumber = 2, forename = "Jack", surname = "Ryan" };
        member1.products.Add(new Products { name = "Health Ins", cost = 100 });
        member1.products.Add(new Products { name = "Travel Ins", cost = 150 });

        members.Add(member1);
        members.Add(member2);
        members.Add(member3);
    }
    // GET: api/Members
    public List<Member> Get()
    {
        return members;
    }

    // GET: api/Members/5
    public Member Get(int id)
    {
        return members.Where(x => x.memberNumber == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```